# S/4HANA Cloud SDK for Javascript and destination service

Tags: javascript, s4sdk

Is "S/4HANA Cloud SDK for Javascript beta" already supporting the destination service in SAP Cloud Foundry? I did some tests, but without success. For example, retrieving business partners only works when I define the destination as an environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile the SDK also supports destinations with version 1.0.0: https://blogs.sap.com/2019/03/28/announcing-the-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-for-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** See Philipp's answer, it is now supported.

Currently, the beta only supports a "destinations" environment variable, or providing the configuration explicitly in the `execute` method.